# drupal site crash and went to maintenance mode

Tags: database, maintenance-mode

While creating a huge volume of pages in drupal website, our live site went down after 5 hours. We investigated logs on Apache, PHP and MySQL thoroughly but couldn't identify any specific cause or error for the site crash.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your server crashed (ran out of memory).  You can start by restarting MySQL, otherwise just restart the entire server to get things going again.

Comment: Thankyou @van! still not understand,This error is coming in mysql_error.log file ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)

Comment: Right, so the MySQL server crashed during your operations.  If you are doing massive operations on the database it would be best to break them up into smaller chunks, try executing them in a maximum of 30 second chunks.  Otherwise MySQL will try to load it all into memory and when it runs out of memory, it dies.